# How do I make sprites in pygame not move through eachother?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game in pygame and I'm having some trouble with object collisions.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.math import Vector2

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Environment Variables
gravity = -1
jumpForce = 20
moveSpeed = 10

#Game Objects
playerPos = Vector2(230,230)
playerVelo = Vector2(0,0)
player = pygame.Rect(playerPos.x,playerPos.y, 20, 20) 

boxPos = Vector2(350,480)
box = pygame.Rect(boxPos.x, boxPos.y, 20,20)

def Clamp(var, minClamp, maxClamp):
    if minClamp > maxClamp:
        raise Exception("minClamp must be less than maxClamp")
    if var < minClamp:
        var = minClamp
    if var > maxClamp:
        var = maxClamp
    return var

def Draw():
    global player,box
    screen.fill((255,255,25))

    player = pygame.Rect(playerPos.x,playerPos.y, 20, 20)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,100,255),player)

    box = pygame.Rect(boxPos.x, boxPos.y, 20,20)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(10,200,20),box)

def PlayerVelocity():
    global playerPos,playerVelo,player,box,boxPos

    if player.colliderect(box):
        playerPos = Vector2(boxPos.x,boxPos.y-20)
        print("balls")

    if playerPos.y < 499:
        playerVelo.y += gravity
    #if not pygame.Rect(playerPos.x+playerVelo.x,playerPos.y+playerVelo.y,20,20).colliderect(box):
    playerPos -= playerVelo

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                
                playerVelo.y = jumpForce
                print(playerVelo)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerVelo.x = 1*moveSpeed
       
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerVelo.x = -1*moveSpeed
        
    else:
        playerVelo.x = 0

    #Draw things to the screen
    Draw()
    PlayerVelocity()
    playerPos.x = Clamp(playerPos.x, 0, 480)
    playerPos.y = Clamp(playerPos.y,0,480)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

I've tried looking this up and the other solutions either don't work with the movement system I've implemented or I just plain don't understand them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to change the position of the player when the player hits the obstacle. You need to constrain the player's box (`pygame.Rect` object) with the obstacle rectangle and update the player's position. Clamp and calculate the position of the player before checking for collision:

```py
def PlayerVelocity():
    global playerPos,playerVelo,player,box,boxPos

    prev_y = playerPos.y
    if playerPos.y < 499:
        playerVelo.y += gravity
    playerPos -= playerVelo
    playerPos.x = Clamp(playerPos.x, 0, 480)
    playerPos.y = Clamp(playerPos.y, 0, 480)
    
    player = pygame.Rect(playerPos.x, playerPos.y, 20, 20)
    box = pygame.Rect(boxPos.x, boxPos.y, 20,20)
    if player.colliderect(box):
        if prev_y+20 <= box.top:
            player.bottom = box.top
        elif player.left < box.left:
            player.right = box.left
        else:
            player.left = box.right
        playerPos = Vector2(player.topleft)
        print("balls")
```

[image]

Comment: The updated code in the answer covers that case.